# Help parsing JSON in java

Tags: java, json

Would it be possible if someone could help me parse this json result. I have retrieved the result as a string

```
{"query":{"latitude":39.9889,"longitude":-82.8118},"timestamp":1310252291.861,"address":{"geometry":{"coordinates":[-82.81168367358264,39.9887910986731],"type":"Point"},"properties":{"address":"284 Macdougal Ln","distance":"0.02","postcode":"43004","city":"Columbus","county":"Franklin","province":"OH","country":"US"},"type":"Feature"}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).  Simple and intuitive to use.  For me the best available.  Start out with [Simple Data Binding](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes#Simple_Data_Binding_Example), it will throw everything it finds in Maps and Lists.

Like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String,Object> yourData = mapper.readValue(new File("yourdata.json"), Map.class);
```

That's all that's needed.

A good and quick introduction can be found [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes)

And a full working example with your actual data:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<?,?> rootAsMap = mapper.readValue(
                "{\"query\":{\"latitude\":39.9889,\"longitude\":-82.8118},\"timestamp\":1310252291.861,\"address\":{\"geometry\":{\"coordinates\":[-82.81168367358264,39.9887910986731],\"type\":\"Point\"},\"properties\":{\"address\":\"284 Macdougal Ln\",\"distance\":\"0.02\",\"postcode\":\"43004\",\"city\":\"Columbus\",\"county\":\"Franklin\",\"province\":\"OH\",\"country\":\"US\"},\"type\":\"Feature\"}}".getBytes(),
                Map.class);
        System.out.println(rootAsMap);
        Map query = (Map) rootAsMap.get("query");
        Map address = (Map) rootAsMap.get("address");
        Map addressProperties = (Map) address.get("properties");
        String county = (String) addressProperties.get("county");
        System.out.println("County is " + county);
    }

}
```

Now, this whole Map juggling also illustrates Bozho's point pretty well, using full binding (by creating a Java class that reflects the content of the JSON data) will work better in the end.

Comment: Jackson is the only JSON-to/from-Java library I've seen that will deserialize any Json object of arbitrary complexity to a Map<String, Object> in just one simple line.  Note that the casts to Map and String would be unnecessary if a Map<String, Object> parameterized type reference were used with the call to readValue.      TypeReference mapType = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){};
    Map<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("input.json"), mapType);

Comment: @fvu This example was the one I was looking for. It did what I need it to do. Thanks a lot. I run this through a for loop with a new string like the one above. So I need to escape the " on the new string as well?

Comment: Never mind I had a stupid moment when I saw this, LOL. I got everything working thanks a lot guys for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

The two best options that I know of are:

- [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)
- [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)

Using them is a matter of calling one method of the mapper. But remember that since Java is statically-typed, you may have to create an object that has the required structure. (You don't have to, but it feels more natural)

Comment: No you don't, see the link to Jackson simple databinding in my reply.

Comment: @fvu you don't have to, yeah, but it is better in most cases, imo

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused on the best route to take. It seems like every result is different. Im thinking I need clarification of what an object and arrays are what each result contains.

Comment: @bozho the sheer simplicity of simple databinding makes it easy for people to get started, "upgrading" to full databinding is imo something that will come naturally.

Comment: @flu can you point to some good examples or tutorials? I just need a jump start. :)

Comment: With either Jackson or Gson, to deserialize to a strongly typed Java data structure, if the two different "coordinates" JSON structures (one of which is actually named "query") are to bind to the same Java class, then some custom deserialization is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.json.org, under the Java section:

- http://www.json.org/java/index.html
- http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/
- http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
- http://code.google.com/p/jjson/

Pick your poison

Comment: This is a sampling of the worst JSON-to/from-Java libraries, right?

Answer (score 1):

With Jackson, following is the approach I'd take.  Since the coordinates in the JSON come in two different formats -- sometimes an object, sometimes an array -- the solution is mildly complicated with necessary custom deserialization processing.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonProcessingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.ObjectCodec;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationContext;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ArrayNode;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));
    mapper.registerModule(
      new SimpleModule("CoordinatesDeserializer", Version.unknownVersion())
        .addDeserializer(Coordinates.class, new CoordinatesDeserializer()));

    Result result = mapper.readValue(new File("input.json"), Result.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(result));
  }
}

class CoordinatesDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Coordinates>
{
  @Override
  public Coordinates deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
  {
    ObjectCodec codec = jp.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = codec.readTree(jp);
    if (node.isObject())
    {
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      mapper.setVisibilityChecker(mapper.getVisibilityChecker().withFieldVisibility(Visibility.ANY));
      return mapper.readValue(node, Coordinates.class);
    }
    // else it's an array
    ArrayNode array = (ArrayNode) node;
    Coordinates coordinates = new Coordinates();
    coordinates.latitude = codec.treeToValue(array.get(0), BigDecimal.class);
    coordinates.latitude = codec.treeToValue(array.get(1), BigDecimal.class);
    return coordinates;
  }
}

class Result
{
  Coordinates query;
  BigDecimal timestamp;
  Address address;
}

class Coordinates
{
  BigDecimal latitude;
  BigDecimal longitude;
}

class Address
{
  String type;
  Geometry geometry;
  AddressDetails properties;
}

class Geometry
{
  String type;
  Coordinates coordinates;
}

class AddressDetails
{
  String address;
  BigDecimal distance;
  String postcode;
  String city;
  String county;
  String province;
  String country;
}
```